# stacked bar plot in R

Tags: r, stacked

[image]

Hello!

I have a table like it:

```
A    B    
1   55
1   43
2   55
1   89
3   55
4   43
4   55
```

I would like to count for each column the frequency of each categorical value and plot them like in figure.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share you code. and be precise, here I don't see categorical variable in each coloumn but numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) to get your barplot.

Check out this [How to Make a Stacked Bar Chart in R Using ggplot2](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3256_bb10db1440724dac8fa40da5e658ada5.html).

Read the ggplot docs and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully get how your table produces the plot you provide since both columns have equal values, and the plot has 9 vs 6 values.

With R base you could try:

```
df <- data.frame( A = c(1,1,2,1,3,4,4),
            B = c(55,43,44,89,55,43,55))

df2 <- data.frame(cat = rep(c("A","B"),each=nrow(df)), val = c(df$A,df$B))

barplot(as.matrix(table(df2$val,df2$cat)))
```

You would need some additional work on the data to get the colors between A and B similar. Since A and B have different types of values, the plot now has 6 different colors.